# CryptMsgOpenToDecode / CryptMsgUpdate when password is required?

Tags: winapi, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, mapi

I  am reading encrypted messages (p7m files) using CryptMsgOpenToDecode / CryptMsgUpdate. This works reasonably well unless a password is required – in that case CryptMsgUpdate returns success, but gives me 0 bytes output. What do I have to do to handle a situation like that?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you really mean password or the message can be decrypted with the certificate?

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Low-level Message Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#low_level_message_functions) (`CryptMsgXXX` functions) to decode encrypted messages you have to use `CryptMsgControl` with `CMSG_CTRL_DECRYPT` and make [many additional steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before like pooling of `CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg, CMSG_ENVELOPE_ALGORITHM_PARAM, ...`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380228%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#4) an example of the corresponding code. Alternatively you can use [Simplified Message Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#simplified_message_functions) which make the code much more easier.